# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 28, file "Code.gs")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, syntax-error, string-concatenation, template-literals

i am working on google apps script and i have come across an error which i cannot resolve.
the error occurs at the end on this line **return ContentService.createTextOutput("thankyou...**

I can't figure out the error. please assist me.
below is the full code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CIdq1anGwzUrfrNNd08NtgTR-QeHUDHgb4HOlnobmkk/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Examiners");

function doGet(e){
  var action  = e.parameter.action;
  
  if(action == "in")
    return verified(e);
}

function doPost(e){
  var action  = e.parameter.action;
  
  if(action == "in")
    return verified(e);  
}

function verified(e){
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0 ; i<values.length ; i++){
    if(values[i][0] == id){
      i=i+2;
      var verified = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EAT", "HH:mm:ss");
      sheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(verified);
      var fullname = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Thank You" (fullname)"is verified at" (verified)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }
    }
    
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id Not Found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Your code is really bad formatted. It is not a question regarding some bug or error you are getting. There are many different formatting errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your styling, one was how you concated strings. You used: `"Thank You" (fullname)"is verified at" (verified)`, however this is a syntax error, as you need a + to conact several variables/strings to a string or use a template string, you got two options:

- Using +: `"Thank You " + fullname + " is verified at " + verified`
- Using template strings (Note: those are not done in quotation marks but in backticks): `` `Thank You ${fullname} is verified at ${verified}` ``

This is what I think how you mean, but I'm unsure about the last return as it was placed outside any function, I just but it one line up in the last function:

```js
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Examiners");

function doGet(e) {
    var action = e.parameter.action;

    if (action == "in")
        return verified(e);
}

function doPost(e) {
    var action = e.parameter.action;

    if (action == "in")
        return verified(e);
}

function verified(e) {
    var id = e.parameter.id;
    var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i][0] == id) {
            i = i + 2;
            var verified = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EAT", "HH:mm:ss");
            sheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(verified);
            var fullname = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
            return ContentService.createTextOutput("Thank You" + fullname + "is verified at" + verified).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
        }
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id Not Found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Furthermore I suggest you format your code better. Do you use an Editor? Many Editors can auto-format you your code, which makes it much more readable

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Thank You" (fullname)"is verified at" (verified)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

by

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Thank You" + fullname + "is verified at" + verified ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
```

Resources

- [Handling text — strings in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings)